# finding all users in a model in sails.js but not being able to add them to html for some reason

Tags: sails.js

I have a "User" model and a "Lab" model.
When I create a new Lab object, I want to be able to pick up users from a list in a "select" html form...
So, in the view of lab/new.ejs I first display all the users in the User model database in the server console by doing:

```
<% User.find(function(err, users) {
    _.each(users, function(user) {%>
<%console.log(user.name)%>
<% }) 
});%>
```

And it displays the list of all my users names correctly.
But when I try put all these users in a select form just below, the select form return empty with the following code ...

```
<div class="control-group">
    <select multiple class="form-control" name="users">
    <% User.find(function(err, musers) {
        _.each(musers, function(muser) {%>
            <option><%=muser.name%></option>
        <% }) 
    });%> 
</select>
</div>
```

The .ejs view does not seem to see the content of the <%=muser.name%> variable while the server does... Any idea why?

Comment: This is really puzzling. I feel like I am missing something important. When inside a view, does the result of the User.find() query need to be encapsulated in some sort of Post, or get function? The weird part is that the server console displays the result of the query for each element in the _.each loop while the view does not display anything, not even a random character repeated for every element found in the _.each loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be running asynchronous code in your view.  Find the users you want in your controller, then provide them to the view as view locals:

**api/controllers/LabController.js:**

```
new: function(req, res) {
    User.find(function(err, users) {
        if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}
        return res.view({users: users});
    });
}
```

**views/lab/new.js:**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <select multiple class="form-control" name="users">
    <% _.each(users, function(user) {%>
       <option><%=user.name%></option>
    <% }) %>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, friend!! I now understand much better what is going on... One step forward toward unleashing the power of sails with webgl to make a minecraft for cell biologists...  :)

Comment: Finally, someone who understands what Sails was created for!